# write in functions.php

Tags: functions, code

i just want this code to be added in my functions.php, so that it will directly display after my post ends
currently i am adding this code to my single.php,
but i want to add this is in functions.php, this code is use to fetch all the tweets of the respective account,
the code is here

```
<?php
function parse_twitter_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {
  $feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);
  $feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);
  $clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);

  $amount = count($clean) - 1;

  echo $prefix;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
    $cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);
    echo $tweetprefix;
    echo $cleaner[0];
    echo $tweetsuffix;
  }

  echo $suffix;
}

function the_twitter_feed($username) {
  // $username = "Mba_"; // Your twitter username.
  $limit = "5"; // Number of tweets to pull in.

  /* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
  $prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
  $suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
  $tweetprefix = ""; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
  $tweetsuffix = "<br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

  $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" . $limit;

  $twitterFeed = get_transient($feed);
  if (!$twitterFeed) {
    $twitterFeed = wp_remote_fopen($feed);
    set_transient($feed, $twitterFeed, 3600); // cache for an hour
  }
  if ($twitterFeed)
    parse_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
}
?>
```

Comment: ok, and what is your question?

Comment: when i add this code to my functions.php, den it instead of my website, it loads this function,
i just want this code to be added in such a way that it comes directly after my post ends

Comment: In that case you should add it in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't just insert the code in the single.php, or use Denis's solution, but if you want to hook into `the_content` you can do so by putting the following in your functions.php file:

```
function append_the_content($content) {
    $content .= 'PUT YOUR FUNCTION HERE';
       return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_content');
```

This will add directly to the end of `the_content`.

You can call your Twitter function above this and it should work.  You'd be better off using a theme framework with some custom hooks because hooking into `the_content` in this way can get very buggy very fast depending on what other filters/hooks your theme and plugins are using to modify `the_content`. I don't know why it happens, I just know that it does.

Comment: the code which you provided, where i have to copy paste my code which is at the top,
in 
$content.=my code
or before your code ?????

Comment: Put your functions before this function in your functions.php.  Then replace 'PUT YOUR FUNCTION HERE' with  `the_twitter_feed('username')`.  You can test it by just pasting the function and not changing anything.  Your template page should show PUT YOUR FUNCTION HERE right after your content.  If this shows but things get messed up when you replace that with your function it means that there some other plugin or theme hook that's interfering with your `$content` hook. I tested this on two of my sites.  On one it worked fine, the other it put the function up in the header and I don't know why.

Comment: hey when i tried the above code i am getting this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function parse_feed() in wp-content\themes\cityguide\functions.php on line 64

Comment: It's because wordpress is executing your `the_twitter_feed($username)` function which calls the `parse_feed()` function before it is defined.  You need to make sure that a function is defined before you call it which is easy when it's all in the same file, but I'm not sure where the `parse_feed()` function is defined so I can't tell you specifically what to change.  If its in a seperate file then it has to do with the order in which wordpress initiates different parts of the site and I can't help you much with that because it's a little out of my league.

Answer (score 2):

Using FTP, grab your theme's functions.php, and add the above code within it, minus the leading `<?php` and the trailing `?>`, towards the latter file's end (before the `?>`, which terminates php).

---

I've edited your function so it can then be used in a template:

```
<?php the_twitter_feed('username'); ?>
```

Comment: i tried that, but it is giving just the output of this function file, not the website

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `<?php` and `?>` parts from the above code, and placed the resulting code within the functions.php file's `<?php` and `?>` parts?

Comment: yes, yes i removed it, and then i inserted the code in that file

Comment: @Denis see bottom of the code, this is not just a function - it runs and echoes stuff. PS no caching, no WP APIs used where they should be... Twitter inspires some terrible code as usual. :(

Comment: Yeah, I actually noted after reading a bit further... Sigh...

Comment: but how can i make work like a plugin ?????

Comment: @ntechi: try inserting the code in your template rather than in the functions.php file. That would be a good start, even if it results in a very slow site.

Comment: yaa i tried this and it working, but i want to make it in plugin format, cause i want to change the username on every post, just like a function of a plugin

Comment: I've edited your code so a function can then be used in a template. My answer was edited accordingly.

Comment: In the future, that said, I suspect that elance.com or similar sites, or outright hiring someone you trust, might be better venues for this kind of question.