# append_content help

Tags: content, the-content

i have a function in my plugin `append_the_content($content)` this is used to display my function inside the post, but it is coming before the post, i want to make it after the post, for this i tried this code, but then too its not coming

```
function parse_twitter_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {
  $feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);
  $feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);
  $clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);

  $amount = count($clean) - 1;

  echo $prefix;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
    $cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);
    echo $tweetprefix;
    echo $cleaner[0];
    echo $tweetsuffix;
  }

  echo $suffix;
}

function the_twitter_feed($username) {
  // $username = "Mba_"; // Your twitter username.
  $limit = "5"; // Number of tweets to fetch.

  /* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
  $prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
  $suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
  $tweetprefix = "<b>".$username.": </b> "; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
  $tweetsuffix = "<br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

  $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" . $limit;

  $twitterFeed = get_transient($feed);
  if (!$twitterFeed) {
    $twitterFeed = wp_remote_fopen($feed);
    set_transient($feed, $twitterFeed, 3600); // cache for an hour
  }
  if ($twitterFeed)
    parse_twitter_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
}

function append_the_content($content) {
    if(get_option('tweetID')!=null){
    $content .= "<div class='post'><p>".the_twitter_feed(get_option('tweetID'))."</p></div>";
       echo $content;
      }
       else{
       return $content;
       }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_content');

add_action('admin_menu','tweet_fetch');

function tweet_fetch(){
add_options_page('Tweet','Tweet', 8, 'tweet', 'tweet_fetcher');
}
function tweet_fetcher(){
?>
<h2>Tweet Fetcher options</h2>
<table>
<form method='post' action='options.php' style='margin:0 20px;'>
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
<tr><td>Twitter UserID:</td><td><input type="text" name="tweetID"  value="<?php echo get_option('tweetID'); ?>" <?php echo get_option('tweetID'); ?> />
</td></tr>

<input type='hidden' name='action' value='update'/>
<input type='hidden' name='page_options' value='tweetID'/>

<tr><td><p class='submit'>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update Options &raquo;'/>
</p></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
```

how can i make it after the post???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited, try this

```
<?php

function parse_twitter_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {
    $feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);
    $feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);
    $clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);

    $amount = count($clean) - 1;

    $output = $prefix;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
        $cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);
        $output .= $tweetprefix;
        $output .= $cleaner[0];
        $output .= $tweetsuffix;
    }

    $output .= $suffix;

    return $output;
}

function the_twitter_feed($username) {
    // $username = "Mba_"; // Your twitter username.
    $limit = "5"; // Number of tweets to fetch.

    /* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
    $prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
    $suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
    $tweetprefix = "<b>" . $username . ": </b> "; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
    $tweetsuffix = "<br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

    $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" .
        $limit;

    $twitterFeed = get_transient($feed);
    if (!$twitterFeed) {
        $twitterFeed = wp_remote_fopen($feed);
        set_transient($feed, $twitterFeed, 3600); // cache for an hour
    }
    if ($twitterFeed)
        return parse_twitter_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
}

function append_the_content($content) {
    if (get_option('tweetID') != null) {
        $content .= "<div class='post'><p>" . the_twitter_feed(get_option('tweetID')) .
            "</p></div>";
        return $content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_content');

add_action('admin_menu', 'tweet_fetch');

function tweet_fetch() {
    add_options_page('Tweet', 'Tweet', 8, 'tweet', 'tweet_fetcher');
}

function tweet_fetcher() {

?>
<h2>Tweet Fetcher options</h2>
<table>
<form method='post' action='options.php' style='margin:0 20px;'>
<?php

    wp_nonce_field('update-options');

?>
<tr><td>Twitter UserID:</td><td><input type="text" name="tweetID"  value="<?php

    echo get_option('tweetID');

?>" <?php

    echo get_option('tweetID');

?> />
</td></tr>

<input type='hidden' name='action' value='update'/>
<input type='hidden' name='page_options' value='tweetID'/>

<tr><td><p class='submit'>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update Options &raquo;'/>
</p></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: no still not working, still the content is coming after the tweets

Comment: edited.. try now

Comment: hey now i tried the code but the problem is now i am getting the div box after my content, but the tweets are not coming now y is it so?
also if i try to get the tweets manually with the help of function, then also i am not getting them

Comment: edited.. that should be it

Comment: hey it worked, thanks a lot for your help
can you just xplain me, what you did?

Comment: most of the times, you werer echoing the text directly, so the twitter part was echo'ing first and the content part was returned and echo'ed later. I replaced all echo's and returned them so they first append to content and at the end we return the edited content back to wordpress (for other plugins to manipulate or) to echo it on screen

Comment: ok thanks alot mate,
hey a last question, i tried to add shortcode, but when i use it, it gives me array
i tried this
`add_shortcode('tweet','the_twitter_feed');`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `the_twitter_feed()` function `echo`es results instead of `return`ing them.

Comment: so how can i bring it after the post?

Comment: Adjusting the function to return(or support both return/echo), or writing a new one that returns instead of echoing it's result..

Comment: so in that case what i have to do?
plz just tell what changes i have to make?

Comment: Having tracked down your function: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5181/write-in-functions-php ... i'd say you need to trace where `parse_feed` is defined(it's not a WordPress function) and find an alternative that can return the data.

Comment: sorry to say this but still i am not getting you, i just started php,
just tell where code is to be changed
sorry to ask this question,
but can you tell me where i need to change the code?

Comment: I cannot tell you where because i do not have access to the function your code is calling, `parse_feed()`...

Comment: ok i ll paste the entire code over here
see my original answer

Comment: *sigh* ... It's still missing the function in question.