# echo or return?

Tags: twitter, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [append_content help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5331/append-content-help)

i have a code which is use to display twitter tweets but the problem is, it is displaying before the content of post,
i know the problem is with echo, cause it is echoing first and then the post is coming, so the post comes after the tweets,
when i tried to make the echoes to return then the tweets are not coming
here is my code

```
function append_the_content1($content) {
 //if(get_option('tweetID')!=null){
    $content .= "<div class='post'><p>".tweet(get_option('tweetID'))."</p></div>";
      return $content;
   //}
    //else{
    //return $content;
    //}
}
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_content1');
function tweet(){
$doc = new DOMDocument();
if (get_option('tweetID') != null) {
if($doc->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'.get_option('tweetID').'.rss')) {
  $output = "<ul>";


  # number of <li> elements to display.  20 is the maximum
  $max_tweets = 5;    

  $i = 1;
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    # fetch the title from the RSS feed. 
    # Note: 'pubDate' and 'link' are also useful (I use them in the sidebar of this blog)
    $tweet = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    # the title of each tweet starts with "username: " which I want to remove
    $tweet = substr($tweet, stripos($tweet, ':') + 1);   

    # OPTIONAL: turn URLs into links
    $tweet = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', 
          '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $tweet);

    # OPTIONAL: turn @replies into links
    $tweet = preg_replace("/@([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/", 
          "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>", 
          $tweet);

    $output = "Twiiter Updates:<li>". $tweet  . "</li>\n";


    if($i++ >= $max_tweets) break;
  }
   $output = "</ul>\n";
  return $output;
}
}
}
```

Comment: no there is no error of duplicate entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions can only return one value. Change all the `echo` statements in your `tweet` function to concatenate a string, then return the string at the end of the function.

Comment: i tried that also, but then the tweets are not coming, see my original code, i changed it

Comment: You are not concatenating a string, you are repeatedly overwriting it. Each time you assign a new string to $output you lose whatever you put in that variable before. Concatenation uses the `.` operator.