# Specific Post Format Image Thumbnail

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, post-formats

I have a post thumbnail set for standard posts (when an image is featured) but for image format posts I'd like to have a separate, dynamically resizing (i.e. image resizing in the functions php via add_image_size), thumbnail.  I found this snippet from the codex:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
echo 'this is the video format';
}
```

I've tried using it on my index.php with 0 success.  Am I on the right track or should I be doing something completely different?

Comment: What do you mean by, "*dynamically resizing, thumbnail*"? The intermediate image sizes are *static*.

Comment: This is all I meant: add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 640, 250, true ); add_image_size( 'image-format', 630, 9999, true );

Comment: So is your issue that you don't see that text echoing on the index.php page? or are you lacking the code to display your custom image size?

Comment: I tried echoing php has_post_thumbnail blah blah and it ended up completely rearranging the index page's structure in really weird ways so I just presumed it wouldn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> This is all I meant: `add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 640, 250, true ); add_image_size( 'image-format', 630, 9999, true );`

So, let's assume you create custom image sizes for `gallery` and `video` (as well as a "default" size, which we'll call `standard`), perhaps like so:

```
<?php
add_image_size( 'index-standard', 640, 250, true );
add_image_size( 'image-gallery', 630, 9999, true );
add_image_size( 'image-video', 700, 9999, true );
?>
```

Now, in your template, where you want to output the custom image size, let's figure out which one to use, via [`get_post_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format), like so:

```
<?php
// Determine post format
$post_format = ( get_post_format() ? get_post_format() : 'standard' );
// Set image size based on post format
$thumbnail_size = 'image-' . $post_format;
// Output post thumbnail
the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail_size );
?>
```

That should be it.

Note: By using `get_post_format()`, all you have to do is register the image size for each supported format, and you're done. You *can* use `has_post_format()`, but you'd have to add explicit code for each supported format, like so:

```
<?php
$thumbnail_size = 'image-standard';
if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' ) ) {
    $thumbnail_size = 'image-gallery';   
} else if ( has_post_format( 'video' ) ) {
    $thumbnail_size = 'image-video';   
}
the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail_size );
?>
```

You could also use a `switch` instead of an `if/else`; either way, it's more efficient to use the `get_post_format()` method, above.

Comment: I'm trying out both of your methods right now.  Quick question though.  What exactly is going on here -> $post_format = ( get_post_format() ? get_post_format() : 'standard' ); ... Specifically the ... get_post_format() ? get_post_format()

Comment: I got it to work.  Thanks for your help!  Still curious about the "?" between the two get_post_format's

Comment: @pope: it's called [Ternary Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Perl.2C_PHP), it's essentially a shorthand way of writing an if/then/else.  In this case, `IF there's a post format (?) THEN return the format to the variable, otherwise (ELSE :) return the string 'standard'`.  So the syntax is basically `(condition) ? true : else `

Comment: @EvanMattson nailed it. :) Here are [the PHP.net docs for the ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: @EvanMattson Thanks so much to the both of you.  I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your comments on the question lead me to believe that you are having trouble outputting the content correctly. You said you're echoing the output; try to return it instead:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
  $content = 'this is the video format';
}
return $content;
```

This may work if your content from this script is being output "before" the main post output, but instead you want it "inside" the main post output.

See [append_content help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5331/append-content-help) for further discussion which might be helpful.